# Can reconstituted limestone blocks be rendered?

Tags: render, limestone

I have a small (re-constituted) limestone retaining wall in my yard which I would like to render and paint. I have previously rendered brickwork. I am unsure whether it is even possible to render limestone blocks because of the porous nature of the material.

This is the wall at present:

[image: Limestone wall block]

I have spoken with a couple of people who operate rendering business. Their feedback was either:

1. You cannot render limestone blocks. The finish will look OK
   for a couple of years, **but** because the limestone material is so
   porous the render will flake off.
2. Of course you can render limestone blocks. Additional chemicals are added to the render so it will not be a problem.

I would like to know whether one can actually render reconstituted limestone blocks. I'm unsure whether the firms who responded along the lines of (1) haven't worked with product before, or for (2) haven't ever checked to see whether their work is still good a couple of years later.

For bonus points, please tell me what the difference between regular render and what is used for rendering the reconstituted limestone blocks, and/or how the application process is different.

Comment: I would ask the company that said "sure", what they add. Then I'd go to the company that said "nope" and ask, "what about if you do this?". It would be a handy way to get a cross-check on the "sure" guys. I'd also call in a couple more companies for opinions/estimates - best 3 out of 5 answers wins! :)